# Vercel Serverless Function has timed out error (more than 10s to execute)

Tags: next.js, deployment, serverless, vercel

I have a `next js` application deployed on `vercel` and backend on `AWS` , I do regular deployement to `vercel` (once every 2 days on average ) my deployment worked fine until yesterday when I deployed a code with minimal changes mainly styling. I start getting  `the serverless function Timeout error` (it takes more than 10s which is the limit, usualy it takes less than 3s) . so when I rolled back to the old deployment start working fine again . I tried also to re-deploy the same old working version. and surprise surprise I got the `serverless function Timeout error again.`

I start comparing the build log for the old deployment which working and it 's recent re-deployment. and what I have noticed is the different `Vecel Version` , in the old one it was `"Vercel CLI 31.0.1"`. and the new one `"Vercel CLI 31.0.3"`  . this is the link to know what was updated between the two versions : [Vercel Release](https://github.com/vercel/vercel/releases)

my getserverSideprops fuction is simple and was working for mor than a year with no issue and no changes. it is still working on the development environment.

```html
export async function getServerSideProps({ query, res }) {
  // await avoidRateLimit()

  const apolloClient = intializeApollo()
  let {
    name,
    loc, 
    cat,
    neigh,
    subCat,

  } = query
  
  if (!name ) {
    // would like to save to cache only
    res.setHeader("Cache-Control", "s-maxage=172800, stale-while-revalidate")
  }

 
  let variables = {
    take: 11,
    skip: 0,
    query: name,
  }

 
    if (neigh) {
      variables.neighborhood = neigh
    } else {
      variables.city = loc
    }
  

    if (subCat) {
      variables.subCat = subCat 
    } else if(cat && cat != "-" ){
      variables.cat = cat
    }
  

  let queries = [
    apolloClient.query({ query: GET_BUSINESSES_SEARCH, variables }),
  ]
   await Promise.all(queries)
  
  return {
    props: {
      initialApolloState: apolloClient.cache.extract(),
    },
  }
}
```

my guess is leaning toward the different Vercel CLI versions , but I am not sure . any help ?